# Why don't datetime fields with ISO 8601 values work in iOS webkit browsers?

Tags: ios, html, cordova, datetime, safari

Why doesn't the following datetime field display the current value in Safari or PhoneGap in iOS?

```
<input type="datetime" value="2013-05-22T10:00:00+0000" />
```

It displays a blank value.

Answer (score 4):

In iOS, datetime input fields only work with values in UTC, and only with the Zulu timezone designation.  Neither local times nor UTC times with a `+0000` offset are acceptable.  The inclusion of milliseconds in the time are acceptable.

The following values work:

```
<input type="datetime" value="2013-05-22T10:00:00Z" />
<input type="datetime" value="2013-05-22T10:00:00.000Z" />
```

None of these work:

```
<input type="datetime" value="2013-05-22T10:00:00+0000" />
<input type="datetime" value="2013-05-22T10:00:00.000+0000" />
<input type="datetime" value="2013-05-22T10:00:00-0700" />
<input type="datetime" value="2013-05-22T10:00:00.000-0700" />
<input type="datetime" value="2013-05-22T10:00:00" />
<input type="datetime" value="2013-05-22T10:00:00.000" />
```

Comment: Good answer, but do you know the reasoning for this?  The [spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/input.datetime.html) clearly shows an example with an offset, and says that any [RFC3339](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3339) compliant value should work.